# android connecting restful api with mvvm pattern

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, okhttp, android-mvvm

I am implementing user login and signup with my custom backend in which i get a token when i signup or login.Then i save that token inside `SharedPreferences`.

So when i want to call an api, i call it inside *Repository* which is an *kotlin object* so that it becomes singleton.
In this app when i call api, i should add a ***authorization header***,get token from `SharedPreferences` and assign to this header.

```
object MainRepository {
    private var sharedPreferencesRepository: SharedPreferencesRepository
    private var retrofit: Retrofit
    private lateinit var mainApi:MainApi

  init {
    sharedPreferencesRepository = SharedPreferencesRepository(MyApplication.context)
    val user = sharedPreferencesRepository.getUser()
    
    val httpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .addInterceptor(MyOkHttpClientInterceptor(user.token))
        .build()
    retrofit =
        Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(API_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(httpClient)
            .build()
        mainApi = retrofit.create(MainApi::class.java)
    }
  fun getSomethingFromApi() = myApi.getSomething()
}
```

The problem is, when i launch app and login it works just fine. But when i logout, and login again, because `MainRepository` class is only initialized once application launched, it doesn't get new token from `SharedPreferences`. I mean retrofit instance is only build once.

So how can i solve this problem? Should i add header dynamically for each api call? (There are so many calls that require ***Authorization header***, that is why i did not add header at each request,instead i added an `interceptor`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an interceptor and add your authorization header in the `OkhttpClient.Builder()`.

```kotlin
class RetrofitPrivateService {
    var token = SharedPreferencesHelper().getToken()

    companion object {
        private val interceptor: HttpLoggingInterceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor(ApiLogger())
                .setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY)

        private val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .writeTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .addInterceptor(object : Interceptor {
                    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
                        val request = chain.request().newBuilder()
                                .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + RetrofitPrivateService().token)
                                .build()
                        return chain.proceed(request)
                    }
                })
                .addInterceptor(interceptor)
                .build()

        private val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(API_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(client)
                .build()

        // function to access your API here
}
```

Comment: But it is the same thing. Retrofit instance is only built once, so token will be the one that is taken when we build OkHttpClient, i mean it will not be called afterwards again, am i wrong?

Comment: Every time you call this retrofit variable, it will always call an API using the Authorization Header.

Comment: yes,but i did the same thing too, what is the difference?

Comment: In your example the token is read once at startup, while in the second it is called on every invocation of interceptor which is per http call.